# cannot install ffi gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, ffi

I'm trying to do bundle install in Windows 7 x64, but get errors while installing native extensions for ffi gem. My Gemfile has no ffi gem. The only dependency is in 'capybara'.

The second strange thing is that capybara is mentioned in my Gemfile for "test" environment only, but when I do "bundle install" the development environment should be used. Why does it parse the "test" section?

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'
gem 'rake', '0.9.2.2'
gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

...

group :test do
  if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /(win32|w32)/
    gem 'win32console'
  end
  ...
  gem 'capybara'
  ...
end
```

I can install the previous version of ffi, but capybara needs the new one.

Error text:

```
Installing ffi (1.0.11) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for ffi.h... no
checking for ffi.h in /usr/local/include... no
checking for rb_thread_blocking_region()... yes
checking for ruby_native_thread_p()... yes
checking for rb_thread_call_with_gvl()... yes
creating extconf.h
creating Makefile

make
generating ffi_c-i386-mingw32.def
Configuring libffi
make -C "/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi"
make[1]: Entering directory `/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi'
make "AR_FLAGS=" "CC_FOR_BUILD=" "CFLAGS=" "CXXFLAGS=" "CFLAGS_FOR_BUILD=" "CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=" "INSTALL=/usr/bin/in
stall -c" "INSTALL_DATA=/usr/bin/install -c -m 644" "INSTALL_PROGRAM=/usr/bin/install -c" "INSTALL_SCRIPT=/usr/bin/i
nstall -c" "JC1FLAGS=" "LDFLAGS=" "LIBCFLAGS=" "LIBCFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=" "MAKE=make" "MAKEINFO=/bin/sh /c/Ruby193/lib/
ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/missing --run makeinfo " "PICFLAG=" "PICFLAG_FOR_TARGET=" "RUNTESTF
LAGS=" "SHELL=/bin/sh" "exec_prefix=/usr/local" "infodir=/usr/local/share/info" "libdir=/usr/local/lib" "prefix=/usr
/local" "AR=ar" "AS=as" "CC=gcc" "CXX=g++" "LD=c:/program files (x86)/mingw/mingw32/bin/ld.exe" "NM=/c/Program Files
 (x86)/MinGW/bin/nm" "RANLIB=ranlib" "DESTDIR=" all-recursive
make[2]: Entering directory `/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi'
Making all in include
make[3]: Entering directory `/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/include'
Making all in testsuite
make[3]: Entering directory `/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/testsuite'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/testsuite'
Making all in man
make[3]: Entering directory `/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/man'
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[3]: Leaving directory `/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi/man'
make[3]: Entering directory `/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi'
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src  -Wall -g -fe
xceptions  -c -o src/debug.lo src/debug.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c src/debug.c  -
DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/.libs/debug.o
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src  -Wall -g -fe
xceptions  -c -o src/prep_cif.lo src/prep_cif.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c src/prep_cif.c
  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/.libs/prep_cif.o
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src  -Wall -g -fe
xceptions  -c -o src/types.lo src/types.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c src/types.c  -
DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/.libs/types.o
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src  -Wall -g -fe
xceptions  -c -o src/raw_api.lo src/raw_api.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c src/raw_api.c
 -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/.libs/raw_api.o
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src  -Wall -g -fe
xceptions  -c -o src/java_raw_api.lo src/java_raw_api.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c src/java_raw_a
pi.c  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/.libs/java_raw_api.o
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src  -Wall -g -fe
xceptions  -c -o src/closures.lo src/closures.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c src/closures.c
  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/.libs/closures.o
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src  -Wall -g -fe
xceptions  -c -o src/x86/ffi.lo src/x86/ffi.c
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -Wall -g -fexceptions -c src/x86/ffi.c
 -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/x86/.libs/ffi.o
/bin/sh ./libtool   --mode=compile gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src  -I. -I./include -Iinc
lude -I./src  -c -o src/x86/win32.lo src/x86/win32.S
libtool: compile:  gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -I. -I./include -Iinclude -I./src -c sr
c/x86/win32.S  -DDLL_EXPORT -DPIC -o src/x86/.libs/win32.o
/bin/sh ./libtool --tag=CC   --mode=link gcc -Wall -g -fexceptions  -version-info `grep -v '^#' ./libtool-version` -
no-undefined  -o libffi.la -rpath /usr/local/lib src/debug.lo src/prep_cif.lo src/types.lo src/raw_api.lo src/java_r
aw_api.lo src/closures.lo    src/x86/ffi.lo src/x86/win32.lo
libtool: link: gcc -o .libs/libffi.dll.a  src/.libs/debug.o src/.libs/prep_cif.o src/.libs/types.o src/.libs/raw_api
.o src/.libs/java_raw_api.o src/.libs/closures.o src/x86/.libs/ffi.o src/x86/.libs/win32.o     `echo "X" | /usr/bin/
sed -e 1s/^X// -e 's/ -lc$//'` -link -dll
c:/program files (x86)/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.5.2/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot find -link
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[3]: *** [libffi.la] Error 1
make[3]: Leaving directory `/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi'
make[2]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi'
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory `/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi'
make: *** ["/c/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/libffi"/.libs/libffi_convenience.a] Error 2


Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11 for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/ffi-1.0.11/ext/ffi_c/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing ffi (1.0.11), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install ffi -v '1.0.11'` succeeds before bundling.
```

Comment: Bundle installs gems from all groups by default. You should explicitly exclude groups, e.g., `bundles install --without test development`.

Comment: Something like "cannot find -link ......"

Comment: @Paul I'm on Windows 7 x64 but I can't reproduce the problema 
`
C:\Sites>ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p125 (2012-02-16) [i386-mingw32]`

`C:\Sites>ruby -rspa 'C:\RailsInstaller\Ruby1.9.3\bin\gem' install ffi 

=
Fetching: ffi-1.0.11.gem (100%)
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed ffi-1.0.11
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for ffi-1.0.11...
Building YARD (yri) index for ffi-1.0.11...
Installing RDoc documentation for ffi-1.0.11...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 1.3.1 version of FFI solved this. Still can't install Capybara.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this troubleshooting guide at Rubyinstaller wiki: https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-gems_fails_comspec_autorun. Could be of any help.